# Ubuntu 19.10 stuck at purple screen during boot using KVM

Tags: boot, 19.10, kvm-virtualization, ipmi

I am trying to boot into a Ubuntu 19.10 machine through the motherboard's IPMI's KVM feature. However, it gets stuck on a blank purple screen sometime during the boot process.

I am able to SSH into the machine when it is stuck on a purple screen in the KVM app. The machine does not contain any dedicated graphics card, and uses an AsRock Rack X470D4U motherboard with an ASPEED AST2500 graphics controller built into the motherboard.

On a fresh Ubuntu 19.10 install, the machine has never encountered the purple screen until now. Before this problem occurred, I have installed `xrdp`, `vnc4server`, `ubuntu-mate-core`, `ubuntu-mate-desktop`. `gnome-desktop` was also installed, but has been uninstalled (unsure if it was a partial or complete uninstall).

Any ideas how to fix it? Thank you.

**Purple Screen as viewed using KVM app**

[image]

**Seconds before purple screen appears**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience on a physical machine. In my case, it was the video drivers that were causing this. So I edited the grub file while it was booting (hold the right <kbd>Shift</kbd> key if BIOS, <kbd>Esc</kbd> if UEFI) and replaced `quiet splash` with `nomodeset`.

However, to make this permanent, you will have to edit the grub file. Since you can ssh into the machine, you can edit the grub file after logging in:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

After you make the change above, save the file and update grub:

```
sudo update-grub2
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Ref: https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln306327/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting?lang=en